# Error while inserting data into database using with ajax,php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web

Error while inserting data into database using with ajax,php and jquery, works for a localhost but after upload into server it gives error.

```
$('#sunsubmit').click(function(){
    var insertedvalue = $('#sundayform').serialize();
    $('form#sundayform').unbind('sunsubmit');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "routineinsert/sunday.php",
        data: insertedvalue,
        beforeSend: function(messageinfo){},
        success: function(messageinfo){ 
            var c = customalertbox.render("Message!!",messageinfo);
            progressdiv.style.display="none";},
        error: function(jqxhr) {
            customalertbox.render(jqxhr.responseText);
        }
});
```

it works fine for with in my computer where but however but for a server it even not redirected to the sunday file where insert code is located it direct calls the error function.

Comment: Please show your code to understand your problem

Comment: It could be some issue with your app config.

Comment: $('#sunsubmit').click(function(){
       var insertedvalue = $('#sundayform').serialize();
       $('form#sundayform').unbind('sunsubmit');
      $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"routineinsert/sunday.php",
         data:insertedvalue,
          beforeSend:function(messageinfo){},
         success: function(messageinfo) {var c =customalertbox.render("Message!!",messageinfo); progressdiv.style.display="none";},
         error: function(jqxhr) {customalertbox.render(jqxhr.responseText);}
      });

Comment: Please, edit your question and paste your code there. Did you change your DB server ip on php according on your production server?

Comment: maybe there is a problem with the url param of your ajax request .

Comment: i did all and search all over for a solution but i can't solve

Comment: Please show us your PHP code, and confirm the location of your `sunday.php` file -- is it inside a folder called `routineinsert` ? *(Please answer using full sentence)*

Answer (score 0):

Your success function seems to be missing the opening brace:

```
success: function(messageinfo)
```

It should be

```
success: function(messageinfo) {
```

This is easier to notice if you are always careful about format:

```
    success: function(messageinfo)  <============
        var c = customalertbox.render("Message!!",messageinfo);
        progressdiv.style.display="none";
    },
    error: function(jqxhr) {
        customalertbox.render(jqxhr.responseText);
    }
```

Comment: putting the opening brace it gives the same error.... it works for a localhost but it doesn't work for a server after uploading it into a server